# How to send a post request in Android without using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am doing a post request to a server using `HttpURLConnection` but I got an exception that this cannot be made on UI Thread.

I was looking for information but I have only found information using `AsyncTask` class, but according to Android documentation, this class is deprecated and I should use `java.util.concurrent` instead.

I have found many information (for example, a complete HttpClient class or to use external libraries) but none of that does a simple thing to send a post request to an URL.

Can you point me to the right direction?

This is my whole class that I need to call asynchronously:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ServerConnection {
    private String absoluteUrl;
    String parameters;

    public ServerConnection(String postUrl, HashMap<String, String> keyValuePairs)
    {
        absoluteUrl = postUrl;

        StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : keyValuePairs.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(keyValuePairs.get(key), "UTF-8"));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        parameters = sbParams.toString();
    }

    public boolean Send()
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(absoluteUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

            conn.connect();

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(parameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            return result.toString().equals("OK");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Furthermore, this is a lib project I will call for the iOS application as well, that is why I am looking for a standar java way.

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just created a Thread object and I added my connection code inside the run method.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation said `AsyncTask` is deprecated now, and you need to use `java.util.concurrent` instead, here's a helpful library called [ObservableScheduler](https://github.com/jiang111/ObservableScheduler) let you use `java.util.concurrent`:

```
implementation 'com.jiang.android.observablescheduler:schedule:1.0.1'
```

Example :

```
  public void send() {
        JObservable.create(new JObservable.OnSubscribe<StringBuilder>() {
            @Override
            public void call(SubscribeManager<StringBuilder> mSubscriber) {
                try {

                    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                    URL urlObj = new URL(absoluteUrl);
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    conn.connect();
                    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    wr.writeBytes(parameters);
                    wr.flush();
                    wr.close();
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }
                    mSubscriber.notifyData(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    mSubscriber.error(e);
                }
            }
        }).workedOn(Schedules.background())
                .subscribeOn(Schedules.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<StringBuilder>() {
                    @Override
                    public void notifyData(StringBuilder result) {
                        //DO YOUR STUFF HERE
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void error(Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Ops ! " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Hello... as a workaround at the moment I have created a `Thread` object and I added my connection code inside the `run` method. It works, but I will try to find out if using this approach it is possible to send an indication of success or error so that the main UI can show a message to the user. Your solution is interesting but it only works for Android. I have this code in a library that will be called from iOS project also.